# Can't call the category method by selector from the main class

Tags: ios, objective-c, overriding, objective-c-category

I have a method:

```
+ (id) showModalFromController: (UIViewController*) controller
{
    AxEmpAuthorizationController * autorizationController = [[self.class alloc] initWithNibName:NSStringFromClass(self.class) bundle:nil];
    [autorizationController performSelectorOnMainThread: @selector(showModalFromController:) withObject: controller waitUntilDone: YES];
    return [autorizationController authorelease];
}
```

and I had a category `AxEmpAuthorizationController+CustomLoginVC.h` in which I have override the method:

```
- (void) showModalFromController: (UIViewController*) controller
{
    NavigationTopViewController* navigationController = [[NavigationTopViewController allocWithZone: NULL] initWithRootViewController: self];
    [controller presentModalViewController: navigationController animated: ![self.class isMain]];
    [navigationController release];
}
```

The problem is that the method in category is never called, and I can't find the issue. Any help?

Comment: Never use a category to override a method in Objective-C. It's undefined behavior and probably won't work like you hope.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One issue here is you aren't overriding the method.  The selectors will be the same (I believe) - @selector(showModalFromController:), but the method is not.  For one they have different return types, another is one is a class method (starts with '+') and once is an instance method (starts with '-').

You need to make sure your replacement method has the signature:

```
+ (id) showModalFromController: (UIViewController*) controller
```

rather than

```
- (void) showModalFromController: (UIViewController*) controller
```

Once you've sorted this out, you're one step closer.

As rmaddy commented above, you probably don't want to use a category to override a method.

If you're trying to replace behavior, consider subclassing and using your new subclass in the places you need it.

If you're trying to do something stealthy - replacing this method throughout your application, consider method swizzling (consider this option very carefully).

Answer (score 0):

You have misunderstood what categories are; categories are not subclasses. Your reference to "the main class" is incorrect. Categories provide you with the ability to break up your source code for readability, or to extend classes that are otherwise already set in stone.

That is to say that if you were to take all of the source from all of your categories and put it in the same `@implementation` block (maybe separated with `#pragma mark -` for grouping consistency), it should read with logical correctness. The code that you have written transforms from:

```
@implementation SomeClass
+ (id) showModalFromController: (UIViewController*) controller
{
  AxEmpAuthorizationController * autorizationController = [[self.class alloc] initWithNibName:NSStringFromClass(self.class) bundle:nil];
  [autorizationController performSelectorOnMainThread: @selector(showModalFromController:) withObject: controller waitUntilDone: YES];
  return [autorizationController authorelease];
}
@end

@implementation SomeClass (MyCategory)
- (void) showModalFromController: (UIViewController*) controller
{
  NavigationTopViewController* navigationController = [[NavigationTopViewController allocWithZone: NULL] initWithRootViewController: self];
  [controller presentModalViewController: navigationController animated: ![self.class isMain]];
  [navigationController release];
}
@end
```

into this:

```
@implementation SomeClass
+ (id) showModalFromController: (UIViewController*) controller
{
  AxEmpAuthorizationController * autorizationController = [[self.class alloc] initWithNibName:NSStringFromClass(self.class) bundle:nil];
  [autorizationController performSelectorOnMainThread: @selector(showModalFromController:) withObject: controller waitUntilDone: YES];
  return [autorizationController authorelease];
}

#pragma mark - MyCategory
- (void) showModalFromController: (UIViewController*) controller
{
  NavigationTopViewController* navigationController = [[NavigationTopViewController allocWithZone: NULL] initWithRootViewController: self];
  [controller presentModalViewController: navigationController animated: ![self.class isMain]];
  [navigationController release];
}
@end
```

You are misusing selector names by defining two selectors with the same name in the same class. If you want to override the static method, you should be using a subclass. If you want a different method in the same class, use a different selector name.